# How to write elif command in shell script like elseif or else command in fortran

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I am facing problem using elif command in shell script like I do in fortran.

I have the employee lists of 100 companies. I want to mask out those companies having less than 500 employees. My script is

```
rm -f category_1.txt category_2.txt
var=company
for j in 1..100
do n=$(wc -l < $var_$j.txt)
if [ n -ge 500 ]; then 
echo $var_$j >> category_1.txt
elif       #I know it will not work
echo $var_$j >> category_2.txt
fi
done
```

I know, I should write "elif [ n -lt 500 ]; then". But I want to be clear whether "elif" can be used like fortran? In case of fortran, we just write

```
if (n .ge. 500) then
write (1, *) company(j)
else
write (2,*) company(j)
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct BASH script will be:

```
rm -f category_1.txt category_2.txt
var=company
for j in 1..100; do 
    n=$(wc -l < $var_$j.txt)
    if [[ $n -ge 500 ]]; then 
      echo "${var}_${j}" >> category_1.txt
    else
      echo "${var}_${j}" >> category_2.txt
    fi
done
```

- Rather than old style `[ $n -ge 500 ]` better to use newer `[[ $n -ge 500 ]]`.
- No need to use `elif` since all you need is `else`
- `$i_$j` will not resolve correctly as `_` is also considered part of variable name, you need to use `${i}_$(j}`

Comment: Oh!! Then I had not understood it properly. Thanks for your prompt answer @anubhava